# REP (Resilient Ethernet Protocol - Cisco Proprietary) configuration

Tags: cisco, switch, rep

I've the challenge to configure REP on a ring with 2 4500-X and 2 4506 as you can see on topologie picture. I was able to configure a basic REP ring but don't know how to define the block port as on picture. With my configuration the blocked port it's the 4500x-1 - Te1/16.

Here the configuration applied.

```
! ### On every Switch ###
! Configure REP on a admin vlan
!
conf t
rep admin vlan 1100
!
! ### 4500x-1 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1
! the port must be on trunk or PVLAN promiscuous trunk port. 
rep segment 1 edge
!
! # Port to  4506-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/16 
rep segment 1 edge primary 
!
!
! ### 4500x-2 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1 
rep segment 1 
!
! # Port to  4506-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/16 
no rep segment 1 edge primary 
rep segment 1 edge
!
!
! ### 4506-1 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1 
rep segment 1 
!
! # Port to  4506-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/2 
rep segment 1
!
!
! ### 4506-2 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1 
rep segment 1 
!
! # Port to  4506-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/2 
rep segment 1
!
```

[image: Topologie]

What I'm looking is a solution for the describe problem - How to define certain port as blocked ? What is the best practice on REP implementation.

I read the official documentation and I'm still confuse on. If someone can share with me some document (other than the [official](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12.2/15.02SG/configuration/guide/swrep.html)) to better understanding, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue, read more carefully the cisco doc, take some notes and test. It's working now.

It's ring topology. We should configure on the same switch the ports, one 'edge' and the other 'edge primary' . In my example, I configure 4500x-1 the te1/1 as 'edge' and te1/16 'edge primary'.

To achieve my goal, defining the alternate (block) port.
I found two ways,
- By the command - `rep block port id <port-id> vlan all` to be configured under primary edge port. 
and the port id can be found here on interface to be block : `show interface <interface-id> rep`

The other way is to configure under the port to be preferred as alternate entering under the interface configuration the following command `rep segment 1 preferred`

[Configuration Generator Link](https://8config.com/template/rJuIA4xpl)

```
! ### On every Switch ###
! Configure REP on a admin vlan
!
conf t
rep admin vlan 1XXX
!
! ### 4500x-1 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1
! the port must be on trunk or PVLAN promiscuous trunk port. 
rep segment 1 edge
!
! # Port to  4506-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/16 
rep segment 1 edge primary
rep block port 00817CADXXXXXXXX vlan Y,Z
rep preempt delay 15
!
!
! ### 4500x-2 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1 
rep segment 1
!
! # Port to  4506-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/16 
rep segment 1 edge
!
!
! ### 4506-1 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1 
rep segment 1 
!
! # Port to  4506-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/2 
rep segment 1
!
!
! ### 4506-2 ###
!
! # Port to  4500x-2
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1 
rep segment 1 
!
! # Port to  4506-1
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/2 
rep segment 1
!
```

EDIT : Corrected, the previous config isn't right and I had an working but instable configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As this is strictly single ring topology, just configure all core ports as 'rep segment 1' and then the one port you normally want to be blocking as 'rep segment 1 edge primary' and 'rep preempt delay 15'.

If there is network outage, the edge primary port will unblock and when connectivity is restored the topology will restore to original in 15s.

Comment: I didn't agree with you in this part "then the one port you normally want to be blocking as 'rep segment 1 edge primary' " because on documentation the Primary Edge Port is responsible for the VLAN loadbalancing and not turning alternate port -> "REP also supports VLAN load balancing, controlled by the primary edge port but occurring at any port in the segment."

Comment: Try it, 'show rep topology'. I guarantee it'll be ALT blocking.

Comment: When I configure 'rep segment x' under interface I get the "Warning: The two ports on a REP segment have to be both edge ports in order to activate the edge port functions." And on documentation they said we should configure 2 port edge. I configured as your answer and didn't reach the goal. Neither your or mine answer are correct. I will explain on my answer.

Comment: Here what I get when I type 'show rep topology' 
sw-swi-4500x-1#sh rep topology 
REP Segment 1
Warning: REP detects a segment failure, topology may be incomplete

BridgeName       PortName   Edge Role
---------------- ---------- ---- ----
4500x-1   Te1/16          Open
4500x-1   Te1/1           Alt 
4500x-2   Te1/1           Open
4500x-2   Te1/16          Open
4506-2    Te1/1           Open
4506-2    Te1/2           Open
4506-1    Te1/2      Sec  Open

Comment: Yeah on the switch with 'rep segment 1 edge primary' the other port should be 'rep segment 1 edge' also. Rest of the switches just 'rep segment 1'. I have this in production and tested in lab, the 'edge primary' consistently is elected as blocking port. I could not actually find anywhere in cisco.com the election process documented.

Comment: Have you a 4500-x too ? What is you ios version ? My initial goal of having on two switch "rep edge port" configured isn't possible on a strict ring rep.

Comment: SUP5 and SUP6, various IOS releases, right now in lab  15.0(2)SG7 and in production 12.2(53)SG3.  Try in your topology to configure all switches as only 'rep segment 1' and then for the switch where you want to block configure the blocking port as 'rep segment 1 edge primary' (and preempt) and the other port in that same switch as 'rep segment 1 edge'.

Answer (score 0):

I know, for example Dell's [Force10 Redundant Ring Protocol  (FRRP)](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/force10-s4048-on/S4048_ON_9.9.0.0_Config_Pub-v1/Force10-Resilient-Ring-Protocol-(FRRP)?guid=GUID-28D908FC-E158-403A-819A-6B8ADF0D7B0A&lang=en-us) "can converge within 150ms to 1500ms".

Cisco REP (4500 Series Switch Release 12.2(44)SG and later) is advertised to offer these convergence times:

> 3750ME converges between 20ms and 79ms
>
> ME3400 converges between 40ms and 70ms

[Configuration Examples for REP](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/lanswitch/configuration/xe-3s/lsw-cfg-rep.html#GUID-C9CFA780-2657-47C6-98D2-984F9182B71F)

[image]